# Symfony2 POST variable parameter empty in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, html, forms, internet-explorer, symfony

I made a custom form for the login in my Symfony2 application :

```
{% block body %}
    <div id="login">
        <div class="login_title">Authentication</div>
        {% if error %}
            <div class="alert alert-error">{{ error.message }}</div>
        {% endif %}
        <form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">
            <table id="login_form">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th><label for="login_login">Login</label></th>
                        <td> <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th><label for="login_password">Password</label></th>
                        <td><input type="password" id="password" name="_password" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <input type="submit" value="Connect" id="login_submit">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>      
{% endblock %}
```

I have no idea what happens and I already spent almost 8 hours trying to solve that.
It works on Internet Explorer, Chrome and Firefox on the local WAMP server.
It only works on Chrome and Firefox on the Linux test server, IE doesn't send the post variables.

I tried it on antoher laptop and it is the same result.
I thought PHP was independant of the client's browser ...

Any idea on this ? 
I get the parameters with this Symfony function :

```
$username = trim($request->get("_username", null, true));
$password = $request->get(("_password", null, true);
```

Comment: Do you have an underscore "_" in your domain name? I've seen a similar problem once, and it was due to an underscore.

Comment: No, I have no underscore in my domain name.

Comment: First of all, use IE’s developer tools to see what data gets send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved, I was trying to implement SSO on my application. So I installed mod_auth_vas on the Linux machine. 
I don't know why but after mod_auth_vas was installed I had no "POST" problems.

Regards,

Servietksy

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$request` is `ParameterBag`, why did you mark your `get` to do "deep" resolution (3rd argument)?

Deep resolution is only valuable if you have something like `field[identifier]` as name of your `input`.

Have you tried removing the 3rd argument (`true`)?

Also, you're saying that everything works in other browsers?

Comment: Hello, I tried without the 3rd argument and it doesn't work. I had tried to do a print_r($request->request->all()) and it shows array(username=>'user', password=>'pass') everywhere except on my Linux Server using Internet explorer where it shows : array()

Comment: Have you try it : `$data = $form->getData();` and then `var_dump($data);`

Comment: @Servietsky: It's known bug that `IE` sometimes skips `type="submit"` and `type="image"` fields. However, skipping `input="text"` and `input="password"` fields is a whole different thing :-|